# powershell and bulk modifying ADUser properties with extended schema

Tags: xml, powershell, filtering

i'm trying to create a powershell script that will check and change, if necessary, the case of a URL embedded into a property of all AD Users.  The domain controller has had the extended schema applied to allow mcx settings for the Mac user base and the URL is a home folder path applied to each mac user.

```
Get-ADUser <username> -properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty apple-mcxsettings
```

will display the complete information of this property, including this URL path, as xml data. This output starts with the usual `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` etc, but I have been unable to filter deeper within this output to find the URL which is a string under a key called `_CFURLString`.

In most cases, the path is lowercase, but each word in the volume-path needs to start with a capital, but am struggling to find a way of filtering the property result, to show the string value of a particular key. `Select-String -pattern` does not work.  If you try and pass it into an array, the first element of the array contains the whole xml string, so am looking for a way to filter through all this xml information to check and modify the string values.

Answer (score 1):

If the property value is an XML document then treat it as such, with the `[xml]` type accelerator:

```
$settingsXml = [xml](Get-ADUser syone201 -properties apple-mcxsettings | Select-Object -ExpandProperty apple-mcxsettings)
```

Assuming that the XML is structured as [an XML-formatted PropertyList](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/UnderstandXMLPlist/UnderstandXMLPlist.html), you would have to find the correct key first, and then the value is found in the next sibling node:

```
$CFURLStringKey = Select-Xml -Xml $settingsXml -XPath '//plist/dict/key[. = "_CFURLString"]' |Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
$CFURL = $CFURLStringKey.NextSibling.InnerText
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your prompt reply.  It seems the problem goes deeper.  I tried what you suggested by creating a variable from the results of the "Get-ADUser syone201 -properties apple-mcxsettings | Select-Object -ExpandProperty apple-mcxsettings" and it says cannot convert value and then outputs to screen the content of the usual style apple xml plist <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>

Comment: What does the last part of the error message say? After the xml contents

Comment: with all its enclosed parameters, finishing with "the given path's format is not supported." which gives the added headache of, if i can't read in the value i want to change, how to write back the amendments without corrupting it.  Is further conversion possible?

Comment: "the given path's format is not supported" - did you do exactly as shown in my example? From the error it sounds like you're trying to have `Select-Xml` treat the xml value as the path to an xml file

Comment: Hi, it's the first command that throws up the error $settingsXml = [xml](Get-ADUser AD_username -Properties apple-mcxsettings | Select-Object -ExpandProperty apple-mcxsettings)  It displays all the plist properties in red with the error at the end.